# Error: Could not fetch bytecode for contract at

Tags: reactjs, blockchain, web3js

I am using third web-dev/react to communicate with smart contract but the issue is it is giving me the could not fetch bytecode for contract.

```
Error: Could not fetch bytecode for contract at 0x1c656A3A2780e1861AC054C12Afe1Db654092bc8 on chain 1, double check that the address and chain Id are correct.
at fetchContractMetadataFromAddress (contract-publisher-f5ef16e9.browser.esm.js:4854:11)
```

```
<ThirdwebProvider desiredChainId={11155111}>
  <Router>
    <StateContextProvider>
      <App />
    </StateContextProvider>
  </Router>
</ThirdwebProvider>;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it following the Thirdweb documentation suggestion, using the `activeChain` and `clientId` props. As you can see here: https://portal.thirdweb.com/react/react.thirdwebprovider

I tested and it works fine for me. You can get the client API key at: https://thirdweb.com/dashboard/settings.

```html
<ThirdwebProvider activeChain="ethereum" clientId="your-client-id">
  <Router>
    <StateContextProvider>
      <App />
    </StateContextProvider>
  </Router>
</ThirdwebProvider>;
```

I hope it can help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some foot notes that I use when trying to communicate with smart contracts. Perhaps it could help you as well:

- Check `Contract Address` and `Chain ID` as the error message suggests, double-check that the contract address (0x1c656A3A2780e1861AC054C12Afe1Db654092bc8) and chain ID (11155111) are correct. Ensure that the contract has been deployed to the specified network with the given address.
- Ensure that your Web3 provider (ThirdwebProvider in your case) is correctly configured to connect to the specified blockchain network (chain ID 11155111 in your case). Verify that the provider is functioning correctly and has access to the blockchain.
- Check the contract availability to Make sure that the smart contract is deployed and available on the specified network. You can verify this by using a blockchain explorer specific to the network you're working on (e.g., Etherscan for Ethereum-based networks) and searching for the contract address.
- Check if your application has the necessary permissions and CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) settings to interact with the blockchain node. If you are using a remote `Ethereum` node or an API service, ensure that your frontend application is allowed to make requests to it.
- You might want to also ensure that your application has a stable and active internet connection. Problems with connectivity can lead to issues in fetching contract data.
- Try verifying that the `ThirdwebProvider` you are using is compatible with your chosen blockchain network `(chain ID 11155111)` as Ive found that some providers may have limitations or be designed for specific networks.

NB!! Remember, if you're deploying a `smart contract` to a `testnet` or a `private network`, check to ensure that the contract has been **successfully** deployed and verified. Some network environments require you to verify the source code of the `smart contract` in-order to fetch `bytecode` and ABI, and the most famous one of them all which we can all sometimes tend to overlook, **error handling** so try implementing proper error handling by logging any errors that occur during contract interaction. This will help you diagnose issues more effectively.